# Howto change view format based on domain name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I wanted to know if there are any way to change the view format for based on domain name the same rails app.

For example :

- www.domain.com => respond_to format.html
- api.domain.com => respond_to format.xml or format.json

Thanks all for your help

Comment: You certainly can tweak apache config to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use a before_filter in your controller and set the `response.format` according to the value of `request.host`.

```
class Controller < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :adapt_response_format

  protected

    def adapt_response_format
      response.format = case request.host
        when "xml.foo.com" then :xml
        else                    :html
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach to what I am guessing is your problem.

Why not ask your clients to set the Accept header to application/xml or application/json depending on what format they want? You can serve html by default to support web browsers.

This way you don't need to have two different hosts.

Comment: content negotiation?! are you mad, Darrell!? I jest, I jest. ;)

Comment: @Mike I know, it seems crazy to do use HTTP features for what they were intended.

Comment: What are the pros and cons of using different hosts? I see lots of sites implement their api on an api subdomain: api.domain.com. Some event place their static content on static.domain.com.