# Rails 3 - what's the best way to implement an application API?

Tags: ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Howto change view format based on domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342849/howto-change-view-format-based-on-domain-name)

I have an application that currently runs on site.com (for example), and responds to HTML, json, XML etc.

What would be the best way to set it up with routes/controllers so that site.com responds to HTML and api.site.com responds to json, XML only. Also with api.site.com doing basic API key auth or maybe oath?

Thanks!

Comment: This has been answered before on Stack Overflow in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342849/howto-change-view-format-based-on-domain-name/2343194#2343194). I encourage you to upvote the answer on that page. :)

Comment: There will be a chapter in Rails 3 in Action about this, (but the route being site.com/api, easily changeable). I would encourage you to buy it in about a week when it goes on sale.